# MySQL: Does SET influence FOR UPDATE?

Tags: mysql

I have the following set of MySQL queries:

```
SET @domain := (
    SELECT server_domain
    FROM engine.storage
    WHERE (size_bytes - bytes_inuse) >= 40000
    FOR UPDATE
);

UPDATE engine.storage
SET bytes_inuse = bytes_inuse + 40000
WHERE server_domain = (SELECT @domain);
```

The question is if the SET statement influences the functionality of FOR UPDATE? Will the SELECT statement be executed everytime I call SELECT @domain or once on assignment and before the UPDATE statement? Or is there even a better solution to manage this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't do `(SELECT @x)` when simply `@x` works.  Once the `SET` is finished, it is in no way tied to the subsequent use of `@domain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

I removed the complexness with the SET statement and put the whole query set into a stored procedure (Better for this task anyway).

If you want to test the FOR UPDATE functionality, simply put a SELECT SLEEP(10) statement between the SELECT and UPDATE and run two almost simultaneous queries (Second one without the sleep!). The second query will wait until the first ends.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`ip` PROCEDURE `allocate_space`(
    IN bytes BIGINT,
    OUT domain VARCHAR(60)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT server_domain INTO domain
    FROM engine.storage
    WHERE (size_bytes - bytes_inuse) >= bytes
    LIMIT 1
    FOR UPDATE;

    {only for testing: --->} SELECT SLEEP(10);

    UPDATE engine.storage
    SET bytes_inuse = bytes_inuse + bytes
    WHERE server_domain = domain;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless the MySQL lords know better than me, it's equivalent to the query:

```
UPDATE engine.storage
SET bytes_inuse = bytes_inuse + 40000
WHERE (size_bytes - bytes_inuse) >= 40000;
```

I imagine in your real query you have a more restrictive `WHERE` clause etc.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply! But with your query example I would ignore the FOR UPDATE lock effect for concurrent queries. Wouldn't I?

Comment: Indeed. I don't know enough about MySQL & its isolation/concurrency levels to know if two simultaneous updates can result in the equivalent  outcome of only one running. I'll leave the answer here for now, and @RolandoMySQLDBA can come and tell me how rubbish I am

Comment: Any single `UPDATE` is atomic -- no worry about isolation/concurrency/etc.

Comment: Thanks for this hint! To complete it, is there any official documentation from Oracle available about this topic? Or is there a specific keyword that describes this effect that I can search something about it?